# Prevent Win2D Animated Canvas from clearing

Tags: c#, win2d

I want to keep the last drawn frame from the `CanvasAnimatedControl` to draw on top of it.
Is there a build-in feature to  do this, or do I have to use double buffering.

I want to implement [this](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/4HRIFg/) with win2d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Offscreen.htm):

> Controls are always cleared automatically by Win2D when a drawing session is created. [CanvasRenderTargets](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasRenderTarget.htm) are not. This way, apps have the ability to make incremental changes to CanvasRenderTargets, and avoid redrawing an entire scene every time.

```
CanvasDevice device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
CanvasRenderTarget offscreen = new CanvasRenderTarget(device, width, height, 96);
using (CanvasDrawingSession ds = offscreen.CreateDrawingSession())
{
    //ds.Clear(Colors.Black); // no clear and you are good to go.
    ds.DrawRectangle(100, 200, 5, 6, Colors.Red);
}
```

> Note that there is a method call to [Clear](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession_Clear_1.htm). Without this, the bitmap will be initialized with undefined content.

> To draw a CanvasRenderTarget to another drawing session, simply use [DrawImage(ICanvasImage)](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession_DrawImage_4.htm) or one of its overloads. For example:

```
void canvasControl_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
    args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(offscreen, 23, 34);
}
```